# How to use AddInMemoryCollection in a .NET 6 integration test?

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, tdd, .net-6.0

There is [documentation about how to develop integration tests for .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) . Logically, I want to mock external dependencies (typically urls refering to some external systems instead of a [WireMock server](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net#wiremocknet)) by changing configuration parameters. This can can be done with a method named [AddInMemoryCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.memoryconfigurationbuilderextensions.addinmemorycollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) . I have been using this when developing integration tests for .NET 5. But for .NET 6 applications (typically the ones without a Startup class) I did not succeed in this.

The problem is that I need to find a way to call `CreateClient` and then make sure `AddInMemoryCollection` is called before the `Program.cs` code is called in order to modify the configuration paramters before using them. How do I do this? How to properly use AddInMemoryCollection in a .NET 6 integration test?

Here is an example of something that does not work. `AddInmemoryCollection` does not modify the appsettings value.With .NET 5 such code works (but then I just refer to Startup).

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void ActualTest()
        {
            TryAddInMemoryCollection("http://localhost:1234");
        }

        private void TryAddInMemoryCollection(string urlOnLocalhost)
        {
            var factory = new IntegrationWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
            factory.WithWebHostBuilder(whb =>
            {
                whb.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configbuilder) =>
                {
                    configbuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>()
                     {
                         { "Google",urlOnLocalhost }
                     });
                });
            }).CreateClient();
        }
```

In my Program.cs

```cs
    var googleLocation = builder.Configuration["Google"];
    Console.WriteLine($"GOOGLELOCATION!! {googleLocation}");
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? Please post [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkSeemann I have tried for .NET 5 to trigger the Startup class after calling AddInMemoryCollection . I succeeded with .NET 5. But for this, it does not make sense to post it. In typical .NET 6 applications, there is no Startup. I have no idea where to call AddInMemoryCollection in a .NET 6 integration test so I cannot post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Daan post the code in the question itself, not the comments. Is your *real* question where to get `Configuration`? Have you tried `builder.Configuratiion`? If you do an integration test, whose configuration are you trying to modify? The test's? The WebApplicationFactory's?

Comment: @Daan last time you asked about WebApplicationFactory was a great opportunity to pester Damien Edwards and the rest of the ASP.NET Core team to improve the docs. It's unclear what you ask this time though. The docs show [how to override the Startup settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-webapplicationfactory) and how to [customize individual clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-the-client-with-withwebhostbuilder). What are you asking about?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the feedback. The link you refer to just demonstrated my problem: `AddInMemoryCollection` usage is not described . I just want to override a value in appsettings of web application. That's all. And this works fine in .NET Core 3.1,2.1 and .NET 5. In .NET 6 it does not. The code is attached.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I added some code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please post the *full* test code. `AddInMemoryCollection ` just adds some configuration values. Where are those used? Does some service in your code try to get `Google` from `IConfiguration` explicitly, eg with `configuration.GetValue("Google")` ?

Comment: Besides, the code you posted doesn't really do anything. It overrides the settings, creates a client and then discards it. The new config values won't affect any other method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added more code with a full test. Let's not overcomplicate this. It is clear to me that my code does not do anything. That is why I ask how to use `AddInMemoryCollection` in my integration test in a way that it does something useful: overriding the appsettings before `Configuration` is used.

Comment: The missing piece of information here is that it's impossible to replace the configuration in tests when you read it in the builder phase imperatively in .NET 6. Your configuration values are applied but if you read it up front in the beginning of Main, then the code to override config hasn't run yet.

Comment: an example of overriding configuration in .Net 5 was handled by using a separate appsettings file and hosting in TestServer instead of WebApplicationFactory as per the eShopOnContainers github sample (which you can download and look at). I've tried to replicate TestServer hosting in dotnet 6 without luck so far. It will be interesting to see how the eShopOnContainers project upgrades to dotnet 6.

Comment: Same issue here, can´t really figure out what to do about it the configuration is applied after the services are configured. Guess it´s time to revert to Startup.cs.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```cs
[Fact]
public void ActualTest()
{
    TryAddInMemoryCollection("http://localhost:1234");
}

private void TryAddInMemoryCollection(string urlOnLocalhost)
{
    var factory = new IntegrationWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    factory.WithWebHostBuilder(whb =>
    {
       whb.UseSetting("Google",urlOnLocalhost);
    }).CreateClient();
}
```

You may also add an extension method that accepts a dictionary:

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder UseSetting(this IWebHostBuilder builder, IDictionary<string, string> settings)
{
    foreach (var (key, value) in settings)
    {
        builder.UseSetting(key, value);
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: This might as well be the accepted solution (though it doesn't really use the AddInMemoryCollection, it does solve the OP's problem). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37680

As of right now this is not possible with .net 6. If you stick with minimal api / no startup.cs you need to be careful to register every service lazily and not instanziate anything that depends on configuration. Your test configuration will only get added once your entier `Program.cs` has executed.

There is nothing stopping you from using a `Startup.cs` in .net 6. Then this is not an issue at all. May or may not get fixed in .net 7. We don´t know, yet.